# ULN2003 relay driver (recurring problem)

Tags: relay, gpio, uln2003, jetson

There are seven relays on the board and a ULN2003 relay driver to control these relays. The BCM pins to the relay driver are marked in yellow below. BCM pins are IO pins from Jetson Nano Development Kit.

[image]

When two relays are ON, a different relay that should be OFF automatically turns ON. It does this sometimes, not always.

[I've posted this issue here before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/585207/uln2003-relay-driver).

As seen below, I added a resistor in parallel to the inputs of the relay driver. This solution fixed my problem, but it came back. Can anyone help with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why have you got diode D1 in the circuit?

Comment: There is nothing in the circuit drawn that would explain the problem. Maybe bad connection, incorrect wiring, or software issue. What is controlling the ULN2003, how it is connected and what software it runs? Have you measured voltages at ULN2003 input for problems?

Comment: No decoupling capacitor ?

Comment: Just dropping the same answer, per request. Seeing how the problem was solved, by resistors on the signal line, I suspect there is ground voltage shift. How is the 5V routed to the relay board?

Comment: What are "BCM pins"?

Comment: Where is your chip bypassing?  With D1 blocking, there is little to no bypassing for that chip.

Comment: When it happens, have you check the voltage of the corresponding input of the ULN2003 for the relay that turns on unexpectedly?  Is it high or low?

Comment: BCM pins are IO pins from Jetson Nano Development Kit. When we measure the corresponding voltage input of the relay that opens unexpectedly, I see a value such as 2.15V instantly, but as soon as we do the measurement, the relay that should be closed is immediately turned off (I think due to the internal resistance of the meter).

Comment: The +5V on the board comes from the voltage regulator I designed on the board. With this +5V, Jetson Nano supply and relays are controlled. I didn't add the decoupling capacitor, does this provide solution?

Comment: Decoupling capacitor, on pins chip, shortest connected AShAP.

Comment: I understand the decoupling capacitor, but I'm not sure if this will fully provide me with a solution.

Comment: Anyway, you should connect COM pin as in fig 23 of datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

Without a complete view/picture of the setup it's difficult to know what's wrong.
The diode D1 should not be here. This is not the reason of the issue.
All the other diodes are not necessary, the ULN2003 has internal free-wheeling diodes (connect the COM pin to +5V).
The pull-down resistors on the inputs are not necessary, the ULN2003 has internal pull-down resistors (and NPN transistors don't need one anyway).

I suspect the source of your issues might be the grounding.
You should have a solid power ground between your +5V supply, the relays and the GND pin of the ULN2003.
The signals coming from the BCM (Raspberry Pi?) should have another ground.
Both grounds should be tied at the GND pin of the ULN2003.

You're probably connecting 5V and ground from the Pi to the extension board.
Do you know how much each relay coil draws?
Are you sure this is within the Pi's limits?

Increase/add more ground wires, or use an input stage before the ULN2003 to clean up the signal, like a Schmitt-trigger before feeding it to the ULN2003.

Comment: There is only one Ground on the system, and everything that is Ground is connected to each other polygonally. The +5V supplied to the relays comes from the 5V-5A regulator output. What do you mean by using the entry november into ULN2003? It seems unlikely that I will use Schmitt-trigger for each input signal.

Comment: 74HC7541D or equivalent single IC with 8 schmitt-triggers.

Comment: I can add this to my design but are you sure you won't have the same problem with schmitt-trigger's inputs? What if one input is triggered and another is triggered?

Comment: What are the IO capabilities of the Jetson Nano Developer Kit?

Comment: IO is actually GPIO (digital inputs and outputs). 0-3.3V logic output or input.

Comment: If you see 2.5V on the IO then the output drive capability is too low to properly drive the ULN2003. You should use an interface buffer between the IO and the ULN2003 to cleanup and boost the signal.

Comment: What exactly is an interface buffer? I'm not sure if using this will give me a solution.